# OpenGL gives Invalid Image Format

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, freeglut

I have an Invalid Image Format error which crops up from opengl. I'm not sure if it's because I'm using precompiled headers, or if I'm just not initializing OpenGL properly. As far as I know, I am not using C++/CLI (I chose to create an empty project in VC++ Express 2010). I'm running Windows7 (x64), and my error code is `0xc000007b`.

Is this common with OpenGL? I'm also using Glew, with Freeglut.

The weird thing is that I haven't tried at all to render an image or anything; I simply am trying to get a window to appear.

**The Code**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "triangle.h"
#include "matrix3f.h"

static GLfloat move;
static GLfloat spin;

void init() {
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

}

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void draw_window() {
    int height = 500;
    double width = 1.9 * (double)height;
    glutInitWindowSize((int)width, height);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("opengl_03");
}

void spin_display() {
    spin += 2.0;
    if (spin > 360.0)
        spin -= 360.0;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void move_display() {
    move += 1.0;
    if (move > 10) 
        move -= 10;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char button, int state, int x) {

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitContextVersion(3, 1);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    init();
    draw_window();

    //system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

What would also be interesting to know is how I have a bad image format from this. I've checked to make sure that my release is debug in the IDE, as well.

**Question**

My main question is to know exactly what I am doing wrong, if possible.

**Update**

I tried moving `glew32.dll` to `SysWOW64`, and unfortunately that did not work. I also tried the suggestion which involved moving my `draw_window` function to the top of main, and that did not work either.

Comment: What exactly are you getting this error from? OpenGL *itself* has no notion of an "invalid format error".

Comment: That probably means you're trying to load a 32-bit DLL in a 64-bit app, or vice-versa.

Comment: That could very well be the case, only I have the 32bit dll loaded in my system32 (glew32, in fact). I'll try moving it to SysWOW64 and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

Do not put `freeglut.dll` into your `SysWOW64` folder; rather, add it to your `System32` folder.

At least, try the `System32` folder first.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call any OpenGL functions until *after* you have called `glutCreateWindow` to create the OpenGL window. So take the contents of `draw_window` and put them in `main` before the call to `init`.

Comment: I tried that, along with moving the function to the very top of main, to see if it would work, and I still received the same error. I'll report on whether or not JonathonReinhart's suggestion works.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using [GLee](http://elf-stone.com/glee.php) instead of GLEW.  Both perform the same function (looking up function pointers for OpenGL extension functions) but GLee focuses on ease of use, while GLEW is more powerful.

With GLee, you should get the latest version from subversion as the last released version is quite out of date.  But all you need to do is include `glee.h` and add `glee.c` to your project.  No DLLs needed.  And GLee also loads extensions as you need them, it doesn't bog down your startup code trying to load thousands of extensions the way GLEW does.